# Get registered classes and kind for supplementary views in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am working on a generic `UICollectionViewLayout` that defines the layout attributes for both items **and** supplementary views. my implementation for `func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]?` looks like so:

```
override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
    var layoutAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()
    
    let visibleIndexPaths = visibleIndexPaths(in: rect)
    for visibleIndexPath in visibleIndexPaths {
        if let itemAttributes = layoutAttributesForItem(at: visibleIndexPath) {
            layoutAttributes.append(itemAttributes)
        }
        
        if let supplementaryAttributes = layoutAttributesForSupplementaryView(ofKind: SupplementaryViewType.footer.kind, at: visibleIndexPath) {
            layoutAttributes.append(supplementaryAttributes)
        }
    }
    
    return layoutAttributes
}
```

both `layoutAttributesForItem(at:)` and `layoutAttributesForSupplementaryView(ofKind:, at:)` works fine and compute the frames for my item and supplementary view smoothlessly.

The problem occurs when I am trying to apply my custom layout to a collection view that **doesn not register** any supplementary view of kind `SupplementaryViewType.footer.kind`. It crashes since I return layout attributes for a view that doesn't exist as a reusable view in my collection view.

Is there a way to get the classes and kinds of reusable view that are registered in a UICollectionView? something like:

```
let arr: [String] = collectionView.value(for: "_registeredSupplementaryViewKind")
```

which would return an array (or a dictionary idk) of classes that are registered so that I could skip the supplementary layout attributes if the collection view did not register it? ex:

```
override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
    var layoutAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

    let visibleIndexPaths = visibleIndexPaths(in: rect)
    for visibleIndexPath in visibleIndexPaths {
        if let itemAttributes = layoutAttributesForItem(at: visibleIndexPath) {
            layoutAttributes.append(itemAttributes)
        }

        // bypass >>>
        let arr: [String] = collectionView.value(for: "_registeredSupplementaryView")
        guard dict.
        guard arr.contains(SupplementaryViewType.footer.kind) else { continue }
        // <<<

        if let supplementaryAttributes = layoutAttributesForSupplementaryView(ofKind: SupplementaryViewType.footer.kind, at: visibleIndexPath) {
            layoutAttributes.append(supplementaryAttributes)
        }
    }

    return layoutAttributes
}
```

NB: I remember from a long time ago that there was a way to access internal/private variables of UICollectionView using keypath, which is why I'm leaning toward this solution.

NB2: I don't want to pass the registered kind as a parameter of my CustomCollectionViewLayout, I want it as generic as possible.